# How does Meteor do reactive template with handlebars ? Refresh all the Template?

Tags: meteor

I did some experiment and I found that Meteor refreshes all that was in the `<template> </template>` block, as soon as there is a change for one value, ex: {{test}}, in it...

```
<body>
    ...
  <div id="main-pane">
    {{> todos}}
  </div>
    ...
</body>


<template name="todos">

  {{test}}

  {{#if any_list_selected}}
    <div id="items-view">
        ...
        <ul id="item-list">
          {{#each todos}}
  ->{{testa}}
            {{> todo_item}}
          {{/each}}
        </ul>
        ...
    </div>
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

And a setTimeout in the .js file to look for the both expected change of `{{test}}` and `{{testa}}` :

```
Session.setDefault('test', 'aaa');

Template.todos.test = function () {
  return new Date().getTime() + Session.get('test');
};
setTimeout(function () { Session.set('test', 'bbb'); }, 2000);

Template.todos.testa = function () {
  return new Date().getTime(); //the timestamps will be refresh at the same time that test will do...
};
```

Whatever where `{{testa}}` is placed in the Template, the timestamps that it display will be updated each time we do `Session.get('test')`.

I don't know if it is a valid experiment... So I would like to know if that's effectively right : all the Template is re-render ? Because I thought that reactive templates was something else... more beautiful... (?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found this : [Ractive.js](https://github.com/Rich-Harris/Ractive) !!

“This kind of **surgical** DOM manipulation is more efficient than constantly trashing views only to re-render them, and it scales far more elegantly than manually updating elements.(!) In this example, Ractive.js constructs a parallel DOM representation which is aware of its dependencies on the values of user and messages.unread. **When those values change, it knows exactly which parts of the real DOM need to be updated**.”

http://www.ractivejs.org/
http://www.theguardian.com/info/developer-blog/2013/jul/24/ractive-js-next-generation-dom-manipulation

It is amazing ! Go to do the examples: http://www.ractivejs.org/examples/ and the interactive learning: http://learn.ractivejs.org/#!/hello-world/1

Answer (score 1):

You must use separate templates or isolate if you want to preserve values in the same template.

Example:

```
<template name="todos">
{{#each todos}}
  {{>todo_item}}
{{/each}}
</template>

<template name="todo_item">
  {{name}}{{task}}
</template>
```

Alternatively with isolate:

```
<template name="todos">
{{#each todos}}
  {{#isolate}}
    {{name}}{{task}}
  {{/isolate}}
{{/each}}
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look to that website : eventminded.com
There is one or two screencast that will give you everything to understand how works meteor.
It's better than a text answer i think

Comment: Could you include the links to the screencasts in your answer?

Comment: you may look at those : https://www.eventedmind.com/feed/ebe8aa64-3cf0-48d8-b3cf-6bd8c374b24f https://www.eventedmind.com/feed/d340ca14-d6f2-45a7-bfbe-3006540a0e74 and all Spark screencast from february

Comment: @Rebolon links are broken. :(

Comment: @ian yes, go there https://www.eventedmind.com/feed?view=all and then have a look at screencast from february of 2013, you will find all screencast about rendering and Spark